# Receiving MessageQueue msgs without reading them from the receiving Queue?

Tags: c#, sockets, message-queue, pgm-protocol

I am using the **System.Messaging.MessageQueue** to send and receive multicast **System.Messaging.Messag**e’s on my LAN – this works fine.

However, I have a requirement to receive the msgs without using a message queue.

As the **MessageQueue** uses the PGM protocol (113) to send messages I am trying to build a type that listens on PGM (protocol 113)  using a socket (e.g.  new **Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Rdm, (ProtocolType)113);**). The type is receiving message data but it is in a text format (with a soap formatter section  -see example this example on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219170.aspx)

I obviously want binary data so i can cast it into a **System.Messaging.Message** and get at the real data.

Any ideas on how i can do this are greatly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking purely for PGM use on MS Windows then [Emcaster](http://code.google.com/p/emcaster/) is very good info source with example how to use it.

But if you are looking for more mature solution with broader range of capability then [nServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/Default.aspx) framework should be your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can just peek at them? The MSMQ supports that functionality. Or are you just trying to read messages on queues you don't typically listen on?